# Table Valued Parameter to where clause of SQL Exec Query

Tags: sql-server

I am getting error in my Exec Query like 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value'.
Here is my Query.

```
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(max); 
SET @value = 'tblLedgerNames.ledger_code, tblLedgerNames.ledger_name'; --Its a sample values,Where '@value' based on listview of the form
SET @sqlText = 'SELECT  '+@value+' ,tblSalesMaster.invoice_no,tblSalesMaster.tin_no, tblSalesMaster.entry_date
                FROM    tblLedgerNames RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     tblSalesMaster ON tblLedgerNames.ledger_id = tblSalesMaster.account_id
    where
    sales_id <> 0'  
        + case when @Invoice_No is null then '' else ' and tblSalesMaster.invoice_no ='''+@Invoice_No+'''' end  
        + case when (select count(*) from @List_Cstmr) < 1 then '' else 
            'and tblLedgerNames.ledger_id in (' + (select * from  @List_Cstmr) + ') '  end --Where '@List_Cstmr' is an user-defined table types

    +' GROUP BY '+@value+' ,tblSalesMaster.invoice_no,tblSalesMaster.tin_no, tblSalesMaster.entry_date'
    Exec (@sqlText)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of errors in your dynamic SQL. First, this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value

is probably caused by concatenating `@Invoice_No` (which I assume is  a numeric type) to `@sqlText` which is of `VARCHAR` type. Additionally, you cannot concatenate the result of a `SELECT * FROM <tbl>` directly to a varchar or else you will be greeted with an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Or if the user-defined table has only one row, and judging by the query, it is a list of ledger_ids which I assume is numeric, that can be the cause of the previous error.

If you really must do it using dynamic sql, you can use `sp_executesql` and  pass parameters instead:

```
DECLARE @sqlText NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @value NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @value = 'tblLedgerNames.ledger_code, tblLedgerNames.ledger_name'; --Its a sample values,Where '@value' based on listview of the form

SELECT @sqlText = 
'SELECT
    ' + @value + ' ,tblSalesMaster.invoice_no, tblSalesMaster.tin_no, tblSalesMaster.entry_date
FROM tblLedgerNames 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblSalesMaster ON 
    tblLedgerNames.ledger_id = tblSalesMaster.account_id
WHERE
    sales_id <> 0' + CHAR(10)

IF @Invoice_No IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SELECT @sqlText = @sqlText + '  AND tblSalesMaster.invoice_no = @Invoice_No' + CHAR(10)
END

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @List_Cstmr) BEGIN
    SELECT @sqlText = @sqlText + '  AND tblLedgerNames.ledger_id IN (SELECT * FROM  @List_Cstmr)'  + CHAR(10)
END

SELECT @sqlText = @sqlText + 
'GROUP BY
' + @value + ', tblSalesMaster.invoice_no, tblSalesMaster.tin_no, tblSalesMaster.entry_date';

EXEC sp_executesql
    @sqlText,
    N'@Invoice_No INT, @List_Cstmr UserDefinedTableType READONLY',
    @Invoice_No,
    @List_Cstmr
```

Comment: Ia m getting error when I used the above code ,the error like this .Must declare the scalar variable "@Invoice_No".Must declare the table variable "@List_Cstmr ".

Answer (score 0):

Inner select in where clause using a temp table should also come in single quotes. In inner select you should select a single variable not *

Try This code:

```
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(max); 
SET @value = 'tblLedgerNames.ledger_code, tblLedgerNames.ledger_name'; --Its a sample values,Where '@value' based on listview of the form
SET @sqlText = 'SELECT  '+@value+' ,tblSalesMaster.invoice_no,tblSalesMaster.tin_no, tblSalesMaster.entry_date
                FROM    tblLedgerNames RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     tblSalesMaster ON tblLedgerNames.ledger_id = tblSalesMaster.account_id
    where
    sales_id <> 0'  
        + case when @Invoice_No is null then '' else ' and tblSalesMaster.invoice_no ='''+@Invoice_No+'''' end  
        + case when (select count(*) from @List_Cstmr) < 1 then '' else 
            ' and tblLedgerNames.ledger_id in (select id from +' @List_Cstmr +') '  end --Where '@List_Cstmr' is an user-defined table types
    +' GROUP BY '+@value+' , tblSalesMaster.invoice_no,tblSalesMaster.tin_no, tblSalesMaster.entry_date'
    Exec (@sqlText)
```

Comment: We cant execute these code because '@List_Cstmr' is a table .The error is 'must declare scalar variable @List_Cstmr'

Comment: just create temporary table with # not with @... try

Comment: which solution works. please specify so other will get help.

Comment: Select @List_Cstmr values to temp table #temp ,and replace table type with #temp on where clause.Now it works successfully

Answer (score 0):

Where Select Table Type (@List_Cstmr) to Temp table #temp ,Then Replace @List_Cstmr with #temp in Where clause.
Try this Code

```
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(max); 
SET @value = 'tblLedgerNames.ledger_code, tblLedgerNames.ledger_name'; --Its a sample values,Where '@value' based on listview of the form
SET @sqlText = 'SELECT  '+@value+' ,tblSalesMaster.invoice_no,tblSalesMaster.tin_no, tblSalesMaster.entry_date
            FROM    tblLedgerNames RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                 tblSalesMaster ON tblLedgerNames.ledger_id = tblSalesMaster.account_id
where
sales_id <> 0'  
    + case when @Invoice_No is null then '' else ' and tblSalesMaster.invoice_no ='''+@Invoice_No+'''' end  
    + case when (select count(*) from #temp) < 1 then '' else 
        ' and tblLedgerNames.ledger_id in (select id from  #temp ) '  end --Where '@List_Cstmr' is an user-defined table types
+' GROUP BY '+@value+' , tblSalesMaster.invoice_no,tblSalesMaster.tin_no, tblSalesMaster.entry_date'
Exec (@sqlText)
```